# gecko in vb.net, objectreference needs objectinstance?

Tags: webbrowser-control, vb.net-2010, gecko

I want to implement a Webbrowser in my vb.net (2008)-project, however, I don't like the inbuilt IE.

I also remembered that is was kind of easy to implement a mozilla-tool like the gecko-webbrowser in the past...

It was kinf of more complicated than I remember, as I had to dwnload xulrunner and Skybound.Gecko.dll which both probably have to be included in any publishing of the finished project... I also defined x86 as target CPU and made all the needed steps to use a GeckoWebBrowser within my Application. I also called `Skybound.Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "/xulrunner")` before compiling it.

However, when I try `GeckoWebBrowser1.navigate("http://...")` (The element was inserted with this name per designer) the IDE tells me that an objectreference is not set to a objectinstance as if GeckoWebBrowser1 isn't defined yet... but the `GeckoWebBrowser1.Created` attribute is giving back true.

Does anybody know why it isn't working yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same error in my solution. Try to use GeckoFX assembly. I use 15 version dll and error fix.
https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-16.0/downloads